# What are the real life application of absolute function?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, reference-request, absolute-value, applications

The well-known absolute function $|x|$ has many uses in mathematics, physics, etc. I know one of the majority applications of abs function in the alternative current making with diodes. But it is somehow an advanced application that can't understand by the student of $ k9$. Can someone make it easier to discuss, or bring me out of the darkness of illusion and tell about simple real-life application of that function?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Speed is the absolute value of velocity.  In one dimension, the absolute value tells you the distance to a fixed point.

Comment: Many people use it, possibly without knowing what it is. For example in finances. You don't think that you'll obtain -5 money, you think that you'll pay 5 money.

Comment: Absolute value is a prototypical example of a [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) and norms are quite useful for defining [metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Metrics_on_vector_spaces).  Now... while those words and the definitions of those words may be scary to a young student, the concepts they are used for are very much everyday things.  We can use them to describe "*how far away one thing is from another*" or "*how big something is*" etc... Even non-mathematicians need to have some concept of distance for everyday life occurrences like travel.